# Kotlin: Default value for the argument(s) of generic method

Tags: kotlin

Why this is correct and the below one is wrong?

#### Correct one

```
fun main () {
    AppModule().provideHttpClient(CIO)
}
```

### Wrong

```
    fun <T : HttpClientEngineConfig> provideHttpClient(engineFactory: HttpClientEngineFactory<T> = CIO): HttpClient
```

> Type mismatch.
> Required:HttpClientEngineFactory
> Found: CIO

With CIO being defined as:

```
public object CIO : HttpClientEngineFactory<CIOEngineConfig> {
    init {
        addToLoader()
    }

    override fun create(block: CIOEngineConfig.() -> Unit): HttpClientEngine =
        CIOEngine(CIOEngineConfig().apply(block))

    override fun toString(): String = "CIO"
}
```

Comment: Are you asking why you can pass `CIO` when calling the function, but cannot use it as a default value?

Comment: Yes @Sweeper  that's what I  am asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semantics of a generic method is that "I work with any type", so the type parameters of a generic method is specified by the caller - the caller gets to decide what `T` is. Therefore, the default value that you specify as the callee must be compatible with `HttpClientEngineFactory<T>`, for any `T` that the caller might pass in.

Using `CIO` doesn't work here, because you are forcing `T` to be `CIOEngineConfig`.

Imagine what would happen if the default value of `CIO` was allowed, and the caller did:

```
AppModule().provideHttpClient<SomeOtherEngineConfig>()
```

From the way that `provideHttpClient` is declared, this should be possible - I'm passing `SomeOtherEngineConfig` for the generic type parameter `T`, and since the `engineFactory` parameter has a default value, I don't need to pass any other parameters. But when this actually gets run, the default value of `CIO` is used for a parameter of type `HttpClientEngineFactory<SomeOtherEngineConfig>`!

It's easy to workaround this: simply declare another overload of `provideHttpClient` that is not generic:

```
fun provideHttpClient(): HttpClient = provideHttpClient(CIO)
```

Comment: Thanks for the relatable example in last 2nd paragraph